# SQL inner join between two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, inner-join

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I have 4 tables `StudentAbsentees, Students, StudentSections` and `Sections`

In the `StudentAbsentees` table I am storing the `studentId` that are absent (absentees only) on a particular day like,

```
    StudentId     Time     Date        
   -----------   ------   ------
       1         10:00    2012-04-13
```

and in the `StudentSections` I am storing the `studentId` in a particular section like

```
 StudentId    SectionId
   ----------   ------------
      1              1
      2              1
      3              1
```

and in the `Students` table I am storing student details, likewise in `Sections` table I have section details like name and capacity of that section.

I need to join these tables and display whether the student is present/absent on a particular day... the result should be

```
StudentId    Status
---------    ------
    1         Absent
    2         Present
    3         Present
```

I can get the absentees list from these tables, I dunno how to display whether they are present/absent....can anyone help me here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from (
   select s.id, 
          case 
              when sa.date = '2012-01-01'
              then 'absent'
              else 'present' 
          end as status,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY CASE WHEN sa.date = '2012-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS RowNumber
   from students s
   left outer join studentabsentees sa on s.id = sa.studentid
)
as a where a.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: its showing error like invalid syntax near 'is' and if I remove the sa.[date] its working but the output is wrong

Comment: thanks for ur reponse juergen, its showing all the Status as 'absent'

Comment: sorry sorry, wait I'll check, I think there is some bug in my data, I'll check and let u know

Comment: I verified it with a simple example and the edit I made just now works at least on MySQL. Could you check that again? I changed `null` to `sa.studentid is null`

Comment: I'll go through my data once, and let u know where the error is....thanks again for ur kind response

Comment: @Shanish: Try my current edit. I used SQLFiddle to verify for SqlServer. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a607/12)

Comment: but one doubt, if I put the date condition in ur query itself like where sa.date='2012-04-13' it doesn't display anything..why???

Comment: @Shanish: Oh, I forgot to remove that. Putting a date in the where clause will limit the result to a specific absent date which doesn't fit your query.

Comment: but thats my specific requirement, if I give a particular date, i need to display all the students list with the status, is it possible, can u help me

Comment: @Shanish: I updated my answer. I tested it on the SQLFiddle example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/792ab/12)

Comment: check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f27c/2, y the StudentId 1 coming 3 times instead of 1

Comment: @Shanish: Now it's getting wild. See my update. I used your SQLFiddle example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10107/discussion-between-shanish-and-juergen-d)

Comment: am getting this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f27c/27...... shows all r present instead of showing 1 as absent

Comment: @Shanish: The problem was the SQL Fiddle example using datetime instead of date. You copied the answer into SQLFiddle and there conversion from datetime to date got lost. I changed the SQLFiddle example and now it works with the answer.

Comment: @Shanish: And I changed the `order by`clause. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb9a3/1)

Comment: @Shanish: This is the final SQLFiddle example: [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb9a3/8)

Comment: @Shanish: If you change the date don't forget to change it in the order by clause too while testing.

Comment: thanks juergen, I offered u the bounty, for ur valuable guidance and kind response

Answer (score 1):

You're query to show the status of all students for a particular day would look like:

```
select s.id, s.name, a.status
from student s
left join studentabsentees a on s.id = a.studentid
where a.date = ?
```

Obviously you have to supply a date.

Note: Your question uses "inner join" in the title. I think left is a better fit because it would show for all students. But if you really wanted just the ones that have a record in the absentee table then you could just change the word "left" in the query to "inner".

Note2: My query assumes a status field. If you don't have one then look at juergen d's answer.

Comment: I misread the question and didn't see that status isn't in the studentabsentee table, you should look at @juergen d's answer for how to deal with presenting a status based on null data

Answer (score 1):

No need for joins, you can just use set operators:

```
SELECT StudentID, 'Absent' 
FROM StudentsAbsentees
WHERE [date] = ...
UNION 
(
SELECT StudentID, 'Present'
FROM Students
EXCEPT
SELECT StudentID, 'Present' 
FROM StudentsAbsentees
WHERE [date] = ...
)
```

You can display 'Present' and 'Absent' by just selecting them as constant. It's easy to get the list of all the absent students. Then union this with all the present students. Present students are found by taking the complete student list and using the except operator on the missing students. But in this except part make sure you select the absent students as present so they subtract nicely from the list of all students with present next to their name that you have just created.